# Possibility to set cookie flags to _gaexp

Tags: google-analytics, google-optimize

Is it possible to set that the _gaexp cookie will be created with flags SameSite=None; Secure? I'm using Optimize for an app running in iframe and the experiment doesn't work because 3rd party cookie _gaexp is being blocked.

I'm already using this option for analytics.js https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#cookieFlags but I didn't find anything similar for Optimize.

Answer (score 0):

I am in a similar case, I think it is not possible.

Here you have the same question without response
https://support.google.com/optimize/thread/75547539?hl=en